# ActiveScaffold and DatePickerBridge: Can't convert rails date format

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, activescaffold

I have a problem on my rails app using the staging environment. The error is as follows:

```
ActiveScaffold: Missing datetime picker localization for your locale: en-US
AS DatePickerBridge: Can t convert rails date format: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z to jquery datepicker format. Options %c, %U, %W, %w, %x %X, %z, %Z are not supported by datepicker]
```

I use Rails 3.0.6, Ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i686-linux] and Phusion Passenger 3.0.18 on my staging environment.

How can I fix this problem? Is it a jQuery problem?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add kaminari on your Gemfile and then perform this steps on a terminal
 - `rails plugin install git://github.com/rails/verification.git`
 - `bundle install`
 - `bundle update`

And then `rails s` and the issue is solved